# Construct Exception from String C++

Tags: c++, exception

How do I construct an exception from a string in C++?
-The std::exception constructer takes in a char array.
-If I insert `string.c_str()` then it does not read the entire array but only the first character.

Comment: `std::exception` does not have a constructor that takes a char array (or anything else, for that matter, other than another `std::exception` to copy from).  Classes that *derive* from `std::exception` have their own constructors that can take either a `std::string` or a `const char*`.

Answer (score 4):

**[`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) is constructible from a `std::string`**, as are the other standard derived exception types.

Using that, the lifetime of the string will be managed properly (unlike your attempt, which almost certainly involves dereferencing a dangling pointer).

`std::runtime_error` will also safely implement copy semantics ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception)), which is easy to forget if you get yourself into a situation where you'd have to do so yourself.

You're supposed to derive from `std::exception`, not use it directly.

Answer (score -2):

it wont work because string.c_str() returns a char array of static memory, try declaring the char pointer and assigning some characters to it and use it

Comment: The char array returned by `std::string::c_str()` is not static.